# Change column width (modern CV)

Tags: moderncv

Using [moderncv](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/), does anyone know how I change the command \cvlanguage{}{B}{} such that the column containing B gets wider? As it is now it linebreaks after 15 characters.

I also don't want the changes to affect any other commands

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\cvlanguage` is defined as:

```
\newcommand*{\cvlanguage}[3]{%
  \cvline{#1}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.625\maincolumnwidth}\textbf{#2}\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.325\maincolumnwidth}\raggedleft\footnotesize\itshape #3\end{minipage}}}
```

What you have to do is redefine the command in your document changing the number 0.625 for something bigger (but smaller than one). Don't forget to change the 0.325 to something smaller (ideally the sum should stay the same). For example:

```
\renewcommand*{\cvlanguage}[3]{%
  \cvline{#1}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\maincolumnwidth}\textbf{#2}\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\maincolumnwidth}\raggedleft\footnotesize\itshape #3\end{minipage}}}
```

EDIT:

In newer versions, `\cvlanguage` has been changed to be

```
\newcommand*{\cvlanguage}[3]{\cvitemwithcomment{#1}{#2}{#3}}
```

This can be found in the style file `moderncvcompatibility.sty`.

The definition of `\cvitemwithcomment` are in the files `moderncvbody{i-v}.sty`, and is slightly more complicated, as it depends on the settings for that style of cv. It now calculates box sizes for placing the content.

Comment: Where do you find the defining code of `\cvlanguage`

Comment: This has changed since older versions. I've edited my answer to reflect the new code.

Comment: OK. But as a general question: if you need code like this, do you always look in the `package.sty` file?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes finding the right file in packages (or classes) with multiple files can be hard. The best things to do are look at the texdoc (some of them have commented code) or just search for the package directory in your distribution or in ctan.